# Error trying to running Express and Vue concurrently

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, yarnpkg

My Vue app runs on port 8080. The setting of scripts:  `"serve": "vue-cli-service serve"` and I start it up with `yarn run serve`.

My express server is set to run on port 4000. I start it up with `yarn run dev` with this scripts:

```
"client-install": "yarn add --prefix client",
"start": "node server.js",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"client": "yarn start --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"yarn run server\" \"yarn run client\""
```

while I try to run, it displays an error:

[image]

Comment: This error occurs because Port you want to use is already in used.So, try to configure your server on different port rather than 4000

Comment: Why to set to 4000? Which is my port between client and server is different

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem's solve by using npm package called `concurrently`

Answer (score 1):

See what is already running on that port

```
netstat -a -n -o | find "4000"

TCP    127.0.0.1:4200         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       25160
```

get the pid, for example if pid is 25160 then

```
tasklist /fi "pid eq 25160"

node.exe                     25160 Console                    1    399,528 K
```

So then you can see what is using that port, in this case node.
Also checkout this project: https://github.com/pietheinstrengholt/vue-express-boilerplate

Comment: How it's implemented in Windows?